# How can i receive variables from django-template?

Tags: python, django

I want to receive variable value in my python code from django-template.
I have two button `Yes` and `No`. When I click one of buttons, my python code must receive this django variables and check `True` or `False`. But I can`t find information how to take these variables. Here is my html code :

```
{% with word=words|random %}
<h1>{{ word }}</h1>
<h1>{{ word.word_ru }}</h1>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="no" name="Answer" >
<input type="submit" value="yes" name="Answer" >
{% endwith %}
```

This my python-code:

```py
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST" and request.POST.get("Answer") == 'no':
        return render(request, "training/training.html", {})
    else:
        return render(request, "training/training.html", {})
```

Comment: The value of `request.POST.get("Answer")` will either be `"yes"` or `"no"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite your code like this:

```
# template file

{% with word=words|random %}
<h1>{{ word }}</h1>
<h1>{{ word.word_ru }}</h1>
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="no" name="answer_yes" >
        <input type="submit" value="yes" name="answer_no" >
{% endwith %}
```

And you views.py file:

```
# views file

def index(request):
    if 'answer_yes' in request.POST:
        my_answer = request.POST.get('answer_yes')
        return render(request, "training/training.html", {'Answer': my_answer})
    elif 'answer_no' in request.POST:
        my_answer = request.POST.get('answer_no')
        return render(request, "training/training.html", {'Answer': my_answer})
```

It should work but I didn't test it.

**EDIT:**

You could hide your variable like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value={{ word }} name="word" >
```

Then, get the variable value from this command:

```
if request.POST:
    my_answer = request.POST.get('word')
```

Comment: Yes, code is working, but i want to receive value variable 'word' from django-template

Comment: I tried to do this, but it`s not working. value={{ word }} can`t be used

Answer (score 0):

as follows

```
def test_view(request):
    answer = True if request.POST.get("Answer") == "yes" else False
```

Comment: I want to receive value of variables from my django-template to python code.
```python
{% with word=words|random %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send the word variable by input type hidden  or send by ajax.
If I understand correctly, you want to send variable word to your view? Button value is working fine?

```
<form method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="submit" value="no" name="Answer" >
<input type="submit" value="yes" name="Answer" >
<input type="hidden" value={{word}} name="word" >
</form>
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but its not working. value={{ word }} cant be used

Comment: What you get on view side? None or what ?